# Put an a href link over variables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how i can put an html a href link outside the variables in JavaScript. This is my JavaScript function right now

```
var Investor1 = member(380,0,'UBO',GraphData['Investor 1'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000');
var Investor2 = member(620,0,'UPC',GraphData['Investor 2'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000');
```

And i would like to have something like this:

```
<a href="">var Investor1 = member(380,0,'UBO',GraphData['Investor 1'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000'); </a>
<a href=""> var Investor2 = member(620,0,'UPC',GraphData['Investor 2'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000'); </a>
```

Kind regards,

Comment: And i would like to have something like this:

<a href="..">var Investor1 = member(380,0,'UBO',GraphData['Investor 1'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000'); < href=""> var Investor2 = member(620,0,'UPC',GraphData['Investor 2'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000'); </a>

Comment: `var Investor1 = member(380,0,'UBO',GraphData['Investor 1'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000');
var Investor2 = member(620,0,'UPC',GraphData['Investor 2'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000');`

And then:-

`var link1 = "<a href = ''>"+ Investor1 +"</a>";
var link2 = "<a href = ''>"+ Investor2 +"</a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
var Investor1 = member(380,0,'UBO',GraphData['Investor 1'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000'); 

var Investor2 = member(620,0,'UPC',GraphData['Investor 2'],'male.png', '#C5CACA', '#000000');
```

And then:-

```
var link1 = "<a href=''>"+ Investor1 +"</a>"; 

var link2 = "<a href=''>"+ Investor2 +"</a>";
```

An example to understand:-

```js
var Investor1 = 'First Link to Click!'; 
var Investor2 = 'Second Link to Click!';

var link1 = "<a href=''>"+ Investor1 +"</a>"; 
var link2 = "<a href=''>"+ Investor2 +"</a>";

$('#myDiv').html(link1+"<br/>"+link2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="myDiv"></div>
```